# change permission for a file created using tempnam() from 600 to 644

Tags: php, file, cpanel

How to change the permission of a file that was created by using `tempnam()` function in php to 0644?

I created some temporary file in `/tmp` directory using `tempnam()` and rename that file and changed the location of the file using `rename()`

The renamed file has also permission `0600`, I need to change that permission to `0644` for download which was after loading of the webpage.

I tried changing that files permission to `0644` manually, but once the page was refreshed the permission changed to `0600`.

Comment: Why not `chmod("/tmp/somefile", 644);`?

Comment: for auto generated temporary file?

Comment: You know the filename and the directory right?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat need to chmod the renamed new file. but not for temporary file.

Comment: you may also right, but I was confused with your `/tmp/somefile`. After I checked the documentation I got cleared. thanks for your support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
chmod($file, 0644);
```

Check PHP [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).